# Check if cells in a table row equal 0 and hide row if so

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Essentially what i'm looking to do is to iterate through a table row and check to see if all except the first column are equal to zero. If so then hide the row.

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Player</th>
            <th>Move 1</th>
            <th>Move 2</th>
            <th>Move 3</th>
            <th>Move 4</th>
            <th>Move 5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>James</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So in the above table the first row would be hidden and the second row would be displayed.

Any help would be much appreciated!

---

**Update** : Example : http://jsfiddle.net/3rnbk6s5/

```
$('#table tr td').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() === '0'){
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
    }
});
```

Comment: have you tried by yourself? Any codes you have work on? Thanks

Comment: You can know that before you print the table. It depends on your code then. SO's not a tutorial, try something first and if you have zero idea then hit the books.

Comment: Sorry yes, I should have linked a fiddle I was messing around with
http://jsfiddle.net/3rnbk6s5/
I'm just stuck on how to compare each of the cells and if they are all zero then hide the row!

Comment: put code you have attempted in the question itself. Hint: iterate over each row, then check cells within that row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to find the rows, evaluate the cells in each row and apply a hide class if the row meets your criteria:   **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/01qpd891/)**

```
var tbl = document.getElementById('table');         //find the table
var rows = tbl.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');        //find all rows in the table body

for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {                  //iterate through the rows

    var cells = rows[i].querySelectorAll('td');     //find all of the cells in the row

    var flag = true;                                //set flag prior to cell evaluation

    for(j = 2; j < cells.length; j++) {             //iterate through the cells (starting with the cell at position 2)
        if (cells[j].innerHTML != '0') {            //check if the cell contains '0' (set flag to false if cell is not '0')
            flag = false;                           
        }
    }

    if(flag) { 
        rows[i].classList.add('hide');              //hide the row if the falg remained true (i.e. none of the cells contained a value other than '0'
    }
}
```